# Why do we use the Planck length?

Tags: space-time, quantum-mechanics

We are not able to quantize spacetime and the theory of  **loop quantum gravity** has been proved wrong but we still use the Planck length in astrophysics. Why?

Comment: Also it would be nice to provide a reference for a disproven theory. From your question it is not clear what paper/conference you're referring to. Have all iterations and instances of QLG been proven wrong? The general concept? I'd like to know that, if it really happened.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Physics question, not astronomy or cosmology

Comment: Dunno @CarlWitthoft, it looks like an astrophysics question to me, which is definitely *on-topic*. If you don't think the question is useful, *you can downvote it*. Alternatively, if "physics" questions continue to be an issue, it might be worth us revisiting the [meta discussion](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/450).

Comment: FWIW, the [Bekenstein-Hawking entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#Entropy_and_thermodynamics) of a black hole is A/4, where A is the area of the event horizon expressed in square Planck lengths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you're much more likely to see parsecs, light years, or astronomical units than Planck lengths in astrophysics.

However, for those who like to work in a [system of natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units), the Planck length is **the** obvious choice for the unit of length. This choice has nothing to do with quantizing spacetime. It instead results from a desire to make conversion factors such as the speed of light $c$, the reduced Planck constant $\hbar$, the Boltzmann constant $k_b$, and the gravitational constant $G$ all have a numerical value of one or some other nice number such as $
\frac{1}{4\pi}$.

One way to look at this: Compare the conventional units used in the US and a few other backward countries. These countries have to use $F=kma$ rather than the $F=ma$ used in the metric system. The $k$ is a conversion factor that results from having those conventional units being an inherently inconsistent system. From a modern perspective, force *is* the product of mass and acceleration; no conversion should be needed.

That said, that the mass-energy equivalence equation expressed in metric units is $E^2=\bigl(m c^2\bigr)^2 + \bigl(pc\bigr)^2$ is a sign that the metric system, too, is inconsistent. With natural units, this expression simplifies to $E^2=m^2+p^2$. Energy, mass, and momentum all have the same units; no conversion is needed.

Comment: Also, the formula for the Bekenstein-Hawking entropy of a black hole is simple in Planck units.

Comment: What do you mean that the unit systems are " inconsistent" ?

Comment: @N.Steinle - I thought I explained that in the answer. The customary units used in the US are inconsistent with physics, which says that force *is* the product of mass and acceleration. No conversion factor should be needed, but there it is, the $k$ in $F=kma$. Similarly, the metric system is inconsistent with physics, which says that mass *is* a form of energy. Once again, no conversion factor should be needed, but there it is, the $c$ in $E=mc^2$.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, and I think I really disagree here. You did say exactly that in your answer, but clearly if I'm still disagreeing then you might want to find a different way to explain it.... I don't buy your argument: you seem to be saying that if there exists a conversion factor then the system is "inconsistent with physics." But you really mean that the system of units is inconsistent with our **model** of reality, which is different than what you're saying. You seem to suggest that our models of reality, i.e. $F = ma$ or $E = mc^{2}$, ARE the reality, which is just false.

Comment: The measurement IS the reality, and we convert it to match a model. So, I would argue instead, that the models are inconsistent with the reality of measurement, not the other way around like you suggest.

Comment: @N.Steinle - What measurement? The speed of light is no longer a measured quantity. It is instead a defined constant with an exact numerical value, 299792458 metres per second. The same will happen across the International System of Units (SI) very shortly. A number of constants that are one in a consistent set of units will soon have exact defined values that are not unity. That said, a consistent system of units would beyond useless with regard to commerce, which is the primary reason the SI exists.

Comment: The speed of light is defined as such because we have measurements to justify such a definition. It is not an arbitrary definition. Without measurements to justify our claims, theory is no more than a religion. But some theorists forget this, and also forget that their models are not the reality. (i'm a theorist btw, i'm not digging on theorists).

Answer (score 3):

The Planck length also still has meaning. [This source](http://www.physlink.com/Education/AskExperts/ae281.cfm) describes it as:

> The Planck length is the scale at which classical ideas about gravity and space-time cease to be valid, and quantum effects dominate.

So we may not be sure what happens on such small length scales, but we can be sure that it is *not* even approximately described by "classical" space-time. Conversely, for larger distances, and absent very large concentrations of energy of some kind, it is reasonable to expect that classical space-time might be a reasonable approximation to the universe.